# EF Core - Include ThenInclude Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to load related data using `.Include().ThenInclude()`. I am using inheritance and my classes deriving from the base class `TicketEntry` can implement an interface `IApprovable`:

```
public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TicketEntry> TicketEntries { get; set; }
}

public abstract class TicketEntry
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TicketId")]
    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
}

public class Common : TicketEntry
{
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class CostEstimate : TicketEntry, IApprovable
{
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal Estimate { get; set; }

    public Boolean? Approved { get; set; }

    public string ApprovingUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApprovingUserId")]
    public ApplicationUser ApprovingUser { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to get a `Ticket` with all it's TicketEntries and their `User` and the `ApprovingUser` for all the TicketEntries implementing the Interface `IApprovable`.

I tried doing this:

```
_context.Ticket
    .Include(t => t.TicketEntries)
        .ThenInclude(te => te.User)
    .Include(t => t.TicketEntries as ICollection<IApprovable>)
        .ThenInclude(ia => ia.ApprovingUser)
```

Which doesn't work since it's not a pure property expression.

I tried to look up similar cases but couldn't find any. Am I missing something or is that simply not possible and I'm trying to do something you normally should not do?

Even if one shouldn't, how would you accomplish this?

Comment: You can't do that in EF Core 2.0. Though it should be possible with EF Core 2.1 (in rc1 right now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to include derived in EntityFramework Core 2.0 or older.

There is an GitHub Issue [Query: Support Include/ThenInclude for navigation on derived type](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3910) requesting this feature, which was added to EntityFramework Core 2.1-preview1.

As per [2.1 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#include-on-derived-types) and [What's new in 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#include-for-derived-types) you can use it via one of the following syntax:

```
var option1 = context.People.Include(p => ((Student)p).School);
var option2 = context.People.Include(p => (p as Student).School);
var option3 = context.People.Include("School");
```

### Update: build 2018 announcement & production ready

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-1-rc-1/

> Today, we are excited to announce that the first release candidate of EF Core 2.1 is available, alongside .NET Core 2.1 RC 1 and ASP.NET Core 2.1 RC 1, for broad testing, and **now also for production use**!

Comment: Great, wanted to comment you should write that as an answer. I read through the 2.1 documentation and it inlcudes a couple of features I need. So I'll just patiently wait for now.

Comment: You can use the rc1. ASP.NET Core is in RC1 too and got a got a production ready from microsoft during the build (at least ASP.NET Core did, EF Core should do too though, they are released in sync)

Comment: Updated the answer with the MSDN Blog post, announcing EF Core 2.1 rc1 as "also for production use"

Comment: Thanks, glad to see the features i need just cam out recently. I'll go ahead and update then.